# how to use gmock to mock this class that its instance as a class member in other class

Tags: unit-testing, googlemock

I am a new user with `gmock`.
I don't know how to use `gmock` to mock this class that its instance as a class member in other class.
The codes looks like below:

```
classs B
{
    B_fun();
};
class A
{
    B b;
    A_fun()
    {
    if( b.B_fun() === XXX )
    {
     doXXXXX...
    }
}
```

Now, I want to use `gmock` to mock `B` and then use `mockB` in the `A`'s UnitTest.
Could you please tell me how to do it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can mock class B as:

```
class MockB: public class B
{
    MockMethod0(B_func, void())
};
```

Then use:

```
MockB mockb;
```

And assume that one of the construction func of your class A is:

```
A(B b_)b(b_){}
```

So you can make the mock function workable by:

```
A test_a = A(mockb);
EXPECT_CALL(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Factory method(this is different from factory pattern).

For your case here is an example code:

```
class B
{
    B_fun();
};

class A
{

    A()
    {
        b = CreateB();
    }

    A_fun()
    {
        if( b->B_fun() === XXX )
        {
           doXXXXX...
        }
    }

    private:

    virtual B* CreateB()
    {
        return new B();
    }

    B* b;
}
```

So here you have a CreateB method which is virtual.

Now create a MockA class and mock only this method(CreateB).

The mock method should return a MockB class instance. This can be done by setting up the mock method(CreateB) in the Test Fixtures to return MockB instances.

now put expectations on MockB instance as you want.

In practical:

```
class MockA : public A
{
public:
    virtual ~MockA() {}
    MOCK_METHOD1(CreateB, B*());
};

TEST_F(TestA, TestSomething)
{
    MockB* b(new MockB()); // mock that will be used
    MockA  a;                // class under test, factory method(s) mocked
    // setup mocks
    EXPECT_CALL( a, CreateB()).Times(Exactly(1)).WillOnce(Return(b));

    EXPECT_CALL(*b, SomeMethod()).Times(Exactly(1));

    // execute test
    a.A_fun(3u);
 }
```