# Mocking a class instance created in other class constructor C++ Google Mock

Tags: c++, constructor, interface, googlemock

To give you a bit of an insight into my system - I've got a hardware device that can be communicated with using USB, SPI or UART bus from a host like Raspberry PI or regular PC (USB only). It's a communication dongle and the library should be available to users so the ease of use is a crucial thing for me.

Now I'd like to apply tests to my code (Gtest). I've already made an interface called **Bus**, to which you can inject objects of USB/SPI/UART classes.

The **Bus** interface pointer is in the dongle's class let's say "**Dongle**". When the user creates the **Dongle** class object, the constructor is called in which an appropriate **Bus** object is created based on an enum given by the user in **Dongle** constructor parameters. Moreover it tries to reset the dongle into a known state using the **Bus** interface methods (transfer). Some pseudocode to visualize:

```
#include "uart_dev.hpp"
#include "spi_dev.hpp"
#include "usb_dev.hpp"

class Dongle
{
   private:
    Bus* bus;
    
   public:
    Dongle(busType_E type)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case busType_E::SPI:
            {
                bus = new SPI();
                break;
            }
            case busType_E::UART:
            {
                bus = new UART();
                break;
            }
            case busType_E::USB:
            {
                bus = new USB();
                break;
            }
        }
        
        reset();
    }
    
    
    bool reset(void)
    {
        /* uses the selected object under the bus interface */
        return bus->transfer(...);
    }
};
```

How can I mock the USB/SPI/UART communication busses, when I have to replace the object created in the **Dongle** constructor? I know I could pass the USB/SPI/UART object into the **Dongle** constructor, but this might be confusing for the end users and if possible I'd like to avoid that.

I was also wondering about solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61166003/using-gmock-to-mock-a-class-which-creates-and-instance-of-another-class), however I'm not sure how could I replace the created object with a mock just before the reset() method is called.

Maybe my approach is totally incorrect - any advice is appreciated.

Comment: If I got it correctly, you need to use `virtual Bus* CreateSPI() { return new SPI; }` and override it to return SPI mock.

Comment: @273K is your idea similar to the one presented by AV093 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133758/how-to-use-gmock-to-mock-this-class-that-its-instance-as-a-class-member-in-other) ? I'm just wondering how can I use the EXPECT_CALL macro with a mocked **Dongle** object, when making an object of that type before the macro will simply call the constructor and set it up with a regular bus object not the mocked one. Or maybe you had a different idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have extra constructor:

```
class Dongle
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Bus> bus;
    
public:
    // also used for testing to pass a MockBus
    // Can be made protected, and make friend a test factory.
    explicit Dongle(std::unique_ptr<Bus> bus) : bus(std::move(bus)) { reset(); }

    explicit Dongle(busType_E type) : Dongle(make_bus(type)) {}

    static std::unique_ptr<Bus> make_bus()
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case busType_E::SPI: { return std::make_unique<SPI>(); }
            case busType_E::UART: { return std::make_unique<UART>(); }
            case busType_E::USB: { return std::make_unique<USB>(); }
        }
        return nullptr; // Or other error handling as throw
    }
    // ...
};
```